# XML Alignment not proper

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have created a xml file using jaxb. However some of the elements are not properly aligned.

When I open the xml in word pad or notepad, the alignment of the attributes is not proper
for eg,

```
<a>
  <b>
  <c>
  <d>
<e>

appears as,
  <a>
<b>
<c>
<d>
  <e>
```

What could be the problem.

Comment: Could you provide some additional details about your use case? At the moment there isn't enough information to see what the problem could be.

Comment: what kind of information is required ??

Comment: What does your model look like?  What are you marshalling to (`OutputStream`, `XMLStreamWriter`)?

Comment: I will not be able to share the model. I am marshalling to OutputStream

Comment: I saw a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601143/jaxb-xml-output-format-questions However I could not understand the solution

Comment: The linked question occurs for deep documents, is this your use case?  I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead, it may be worth trying MOXy (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) to see if this problem still exists.  That way we can determine if the problem is due to your mappings or the JAXB implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is based on an [answer given by Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280116/383861) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601143/jaxb-xml-output-format-questions):

- [JAXB XML output format questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601143/jaxb-xml-output-format-questions)

**input.xml**

We will use an input document with many levels of nesting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <foo>
        <foo>
            <foo>
                <foo>
                    <foo>
                        <foo>
                            <foo>
                                <foo>
                                    <foo/>
                                </foo>
                            </foo>
                        </foo>
                    </foo>
                </foo>
            </foo>
        </foo>
    </foo>
</foo>
```

**Foo**

The following is the domain model that we will map to the XML.

```
package forum601143;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private Foo foo;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

In our demo code we will unmarshal the document and then marshal it back out.  I have specified that the `Marshaller` should format the output.

```
package forum601143;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);


        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum601143/input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output - JAXB RI**

Indenting in the RI occurs modulo 8 so we see the following output.  There isn't a "fix" for this issue as the JAXB RI is acting as it was designed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <foo>
        <foo>
            <foo>
                <foo>
                    <foo>
                        <foo>
                            <foo>
<foo>
    <foo/>
</foo>
                            </foo>
                        </foo>
                    </foo>
                </foo>
            </foo>
        </foo>
    </foo>
</foo>
```

**Output - EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

Using another JAXB ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) implementation such as [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) does not demonstrate this behaviour. To use MOXy as your JAXB provider see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <foo>
      <foo>
         <foo>
            <foo>
               <foo>
                  <foo>
                     <foo>
                        <foo>
                           <foo/>
                        </foo>
                     </foo>
                  </foo>
               </foo>
            </foo>
         </foo>
      </foo>
   </foo>
</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Blaise. Let me verify this and let you know the results

Comment: Hi Blaise, use of moxy fixes the alignment problem. However it also changes some namespace values. Any idea why it could have been caused

Comment: @AnandB - The namespace qualification should remain the same although the prefixes used may be different.  It may be easiest to start a new question for that issue.

Comment: Fixed the issue modifying package-info. Thanks for the input Blaise

Comment: Hi Blaise,what dependency needs to be added in pom.xml to download the required jars(eclipselink plugin) through maven

Comment: @AnandB - Here is a link to a sample POM file:  https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20120418/blob/master/pom.xml