# Format Resulting XML File When Using a ByteArrayOutputStream in JAXB Marshaller.marshal

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the below method that is taking a schema based Java Object graph and marshaling it to a ByteArrayOutputStream and later passing that stream to SVN to save the physical xml file.  When I view the saved file using any editor the XML is not aligned and the tabs are off.  I definitely want to keep the marshaling as performant as possible so I want to keep the marshaled object a ByteArrayOutputStream. In the past I was passing in a String to the JAXB marshal method and the output XML was formatted but its not performant to convert to String then to Stream to save to SVN.  Any ideas how to format when passing in a ByteArrayOutputStream to the marshal method?

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  MarshalToObj obj = //retrieve object
        try {
          Marshaller marshaller = JAXBSingletonContextFactory.getInstance().createMarshaller();
          marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
          marshaller.marshal(obj, xmlStream);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {

        }
```

**Singleton for JAXBContext Instance:**

```
 public class JAXBSingletonContextFactory {

      private static JAXBContext jaxbContext;

      public static final JAXBContext getInstance() throws JAXBException {
        if (jaxbContext == null) {
          jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.test.MarshalToObj.class);
        }
        return jaxbContext;
      }
    }
```

Comment: look at following SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601143/jaxb-xml-output-format-questions don't know it's the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling the appropriate method to format the XML when marshalling to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

```
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Any issues you are seeing with this will be due to problems in the particular JAXB implementation/version you are using.  For instance the following link demonstrates odd formatting behaviour with the JAXB reference implementation.

- [JAXB XML output format questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601143/jaxb-xml-output-format-questions)